# Data persistance tableView issue iPhone(reading and writing to plist)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, plist, tableview

In my application I want to implement a simple Alarm function. I know how to use UILocalNotifications, but I came across this source code with a like UI of the iPhone's native Clock app alarm area as well as it having a believe a type of data persistence. Two things I am not good at interface design and data persistence this source code has. But I downloaded it and started playing around with it to find the alarms are not persistent.

[Download](https://github.com/brousalis/neversnooze/archive/master.zip)

Does anyone know how the source code can be adjusted so that it is persistent and the plist can be saved and read to and from? I am open to learning too, this area is somewhat unknown to me too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I review your code and find issue that you not moved your "Alarms.plist" file form resource to document directory. we are not able to edit file which is in resource folder. so write following code in app delegate file.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *theFileName = @"Alarms.plist"; //Change this appropriately

NSString *oldPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alarms" ofType:@"plist"];//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Inbox/%@", documentsDirectory, theFileName];

NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, theFileName];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:newPath])

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil];
```

Perform save operation on file which is in Document directory folder.

Comment: I added the code to the applicationDidFinishLaunching but still the alarms are not saved. But I noticed that even when the app launches it says "Unable to read plist file:" and the save operation never even gets called after I NSLogged it? Is something wrong with my plist itself?

Comment: @user1814207 in your code you never call save method to write data in to file just add object in array please call save method of AlarmListController so your object is added to file.

Comment: Ok, so now save is called but when I close the app and relaunch it it crashes  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf527da0` I figure it must have something to do with the fact the array is confused about there being new sections in the tableView but I believe I solve that with `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self displayedObjects] count];
}`

Comment: I located the .app build file on my computer to see if the new data was even been saved to the plist and it is not.

Comment: This is an image of the crash log  -    [**Image**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ypztcaqa95yd4a/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%202.42.56%20AM.png)

Comment: @user1814207 i am facing same issue, but that is due to you store object of Alarm class in plist file not NSDictonary. see in your AlarmEditController class and try to retrive NSDictonary object.

Answer (score 0):

try this code... to save plist from bundle to Document Directory
Notice that you will have "Unable to read... " just at the first app launch

```
- (NSMutableArray *)displayedObjects
    {
        if (_displayedObjects == nil)
        {
            NSString *path = [[self class] pathForDocumentWithName:@"Alarms.plist"];
            NSArray *alarmDicts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

            if (alarmDicts == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Unable to read plist file: %@", path);
                NSLog(@"copy Alarms.plist to: %@", path);
                NSString *pathToSetingbundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alarms" ofType:@"plist"];

                [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:pathToSetingbundle toPath:path error:nil];            
            }

            _displayedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                                 initWithCapacity:[alarmDicts count]];

            for (NSDictionary *currDict in alarmDicts)
            {
                Alarm *alarm = [[Alarm alloc] initWithDictionary:currDict];
                [_displayedObjects addObject:alarm];
                 NSLog(@"@disply obj %@", alarm);
            }
        }

        return _displayedObjects;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you code, but I think my app's problems are more severe than I originally intended.

Comment: your app's problems are now (I suppose) .. just how you save the data. Test/modify your "saving code" -  check your Alarms.plist (from Document Directory) until it will lock ok

Comment: I think, you MUST have.. an array of Dictionary.. this "newArrayForPlist" must be saved